# Can You Throw Chained Exceptions using JAX-WS & SOAP?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, exception, jax-ws

I have some code similar to this:

```
public class SOAPServer {
    public Object[] getObjects() throws IllegalStateException {
        Object[] objects = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" }

        int index = 10;
        try {

            Object object = objects[index];
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Server cannot access Object " + index + ".", e);
        }

        return objects;
    }
}
```

The client can receive the thrown exception without issue, but it seems that the cause is not passed over SOAP. `Exception::getCause()` returns null.

**Is there a way to throw chained exceptions like this using JAX-WS & SOAP?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to throw chained exceptions like this using JAX-WS & SOAP?

1. There *may* theoretically be a way, but it would most likely defeat the language neutrality of SOAP, so it wouldn't be recommended even on these grounds alone;
2. even when this is trivially supported when using Java Serialization, it is still not *recommended* because you can't control which exception will be the root cause. It may not be serializable, it may hold a reference to a huge object graph, etc.

It is always recommended to transfer just an error message to the client, and to rely on server-side logs for detailed diagnostics.